# Увеличить толщину вертикальной полоски (caret ) в textbox WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Увеличить толщину вертикальной полоски (caret ) в textbox WPF. Цвет задать просто CaretBrush="Black", а вот толщину не понятно.

Comment: Нет, это не поддерживается фреймворком. [Вот тут](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/633935/customizing-the-caret-of-a-wpf-textbox) описан довольно грубый хак с отрисовкой собственного UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть хорошая статья про каретки текст боксов, с кучей примеров : [Customizing the Caret of a WPF TextBox](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/633935/customizing-the-caret-of-a-wpf-textbox)